# Use javascript to change a form label content using the for attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, label

I am trying to change the innerHTML of a label. I do not have access to the form so cannot edit the HTML. The only identifier that the label has is the "for" attribute.

Here is the structure of the input and label:

```
    <div class="fullWidthContent" id="questionCheckboxDiv" style="display: block;">
      <div class="questionLabel"></div>
      <div class="questionCheckboxFormFieldContainer">
        <span class="questionCheckbox">
          <input type="checkbox" onclick="checkdep(this);" onblur="validatefield(this);" checked="" value="Y" name="Question Checkbox" id="Question_Checkbox">
          <label for="Question_Checkbox">I'd like to change this label text!</label>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: and what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [**attributes selector**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) as `for` is just an attribute

```
$('label[for="Question_Checkbox"]').text('something')
```

Comment: use `.html()` to change the innerHTML